# Serializing Java boolean array as 0 & 1s without a custom Serializer

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a `ConcurrentHashMap<Long, boolean[]>` that I want to send to a client app. To optimize the size, I'd like to use 0 and 1 for false and true, respectively.

I have an ObjectMapper that I instantiate so I have tried this:

`objectMapper.configOverride( boolean.class ).setFormat( JsonFormat.Value.forShape( Shape.NUMBER_INT ) ) ;`

That did not make it produce 0 and 1s.

Can this be done using only configuration or will I have to create a custom Serializer?
Thanks

Comment: `boolean.class != boolean[].class`

Comment: "_To optimize the size, I'd like to use 0 and 1 for false and true, respectively_" - Why? What makes you think this is an optimization?

Comment: "_Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil._" - Donald Knuth.  Your _size_ optimization will maybe save you a few bytes in file size, but your code will be more complex, which will add more things that could go wrong.

Comment: @hfontanez "0" is shorter than "false" and "1" is shorter than "true". That's the goal.

Comment: Yeah, but it's a very poor goal considering the work effort. You want to save space? Compress your data (or use a protocol that's more efficient than JSON to begin with).

Comment: @knittl Yeah, I know, but what I don't know is how Jackson is written.  Does it use the configured Serializer for SomeType when it encounters SomeType[], just with iteration?

Comment: @ChrisClark notice how I excluded the word "size" from my question. Your "optimization" will only make your code more complex and error prone and the payoff is very small in comparison. Unless your JSON is millions or billions of bytes in size, it's not even worth the risk. That's why I followed my question with Donald Knuth's quote.

Comment: @ChrisClark consider the time you are wasting here looking for an answer when you could've used `boolean` and be done by now....

Comment: @hfontanez I think it's a fair goal. Sure, the benefit may be minimal, but it is still a valid question with a valid use case. Either there is a working answer or there isn't, but simply not doing it, because it might not be worth it, is not the right thing to do IMHO. After all, we are here to learn. OP can apply the answer and then find out that it wasn't that useful an optimization after all. But if they don't know how to compare both approaches, they can never come to that conclusion

Comment: @knittl There is a reason I asked the OP why he wanted to do this. His answer tells me that, while you are correct the question is valid, there is a much bigger lesson for the OP to learn. If this is a work-related task, he doesn't want to go through the experience of getting "chewed out" by a lead for spending so much time on something so trivial (which could very well happen). And, even if that doesn't happen, it will open the OPs mind to the fact that there is a better way to handle this. In this case, leaving it as boolean is the best choice, and we can explain that in our answers.

Comment: Also, @ChrisClark, please update your code with minimal, reproducible code along with more detail information as to what happened. "_That did not make it produce 0 and 1s_" is not a good enough explanation.

Comment: @ChrisClark my answer is now complete.

Answer (score 1):

Using this class to test:

```
public class Sample {
    
    public Sample(String name, boolean flag) {
        this.name = name;
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    private String name;
    private boolean flag;
        
    public boolean getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }
    
    public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And trying the OP's approach to convert a Boolean value into a number

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();  
objectMapper.configOverride(boolean.class).setFormat(JsonFormat.Value.forShape(Shape.NUMBER_INT));
        
Sample sample1 = new Sample("foo", true);    
objectMapper.writeValue(new File("sample1.json"), sample1);
```

Resulted in this:

```
{"name":"foo","flag":true}
```

So, the conversion didn't work. The OP indicated the typical 1 and 0 values for true and false respectively. The mistake?  `.configOverride(Boolean.class)` instead of `.configOverride(boolean.class)` should be used. After that change, `sample1.json`
is now

```
{"name":"foo","flag":1}
```

Although that works, we run into a problem with deserialization. You can't just convert a 1 or 0 into a Boolean. For this, the best approach is to create serializer and deserializer classes that can be used to convert to/from Boolean. Then, these classes must be added as modules to the object mapper.

---

### Deserializer

```
public class NumericBooleanDeserializer  extends JsonDeserializer<Boolean>{
    @Override
    public Boolean deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
      throws IOException {
        if ("1".equals(p.getText())) {
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        }
        if ("0".equals(p.getText())) {
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

### Serializer

```
public class NumericBooleanSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Boolean>{
    @Override
    public void serialize(Boolean value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
      throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(value ? "1" : "0");
    }
}
```

Now, we need to make two changes to `Sample` class. One, add a no-argument contructor, and annotate the boolean field.

```
public static class Sample {
    public Sample() {}
    
    public Sample(String name, boolean flag) {
        this.name = name;
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    private String name;

    @JsonSerialize(using = NumericBooleanSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = NumericBooleanDeserializer.class)
    private boolean flag;

// rest of the class omitted
}
```

Now, if I update my test `main()` method as follows

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); objectMapper.configOverride(Boolean.class).setFormat(JsonFormat.Value.forShape(Shape.NUMBER_INT));
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(Boolean.class, new NumericBooleanSerializer());
        module.addDeserializer(Boolean.class, new NumericBooleanDeserializer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);
        
Sample sample1 = new Sample("foo", true);
System.out.println("Sample1: " + sample1);
objectMapper.writeValue(new File("sample1.json"), sample1);
        
Sample sample2 = objectMapper.readValue(Paths.get("sample1.json").toFile(), Sample.class);
System.out.println("Sample2: " + sample2);
```

The program outputs:

```
Sample1: { name :foo, flag : true }
Sample2: { name :foo, flag : true }
```

while the created file `sample1.json` contains the converted values for Boolean

```
{"name":"foo","flag":"1"}
```

**UPDATE**: For this simple example, the serializer is not really needed. The only difference between using the serializer and when you use the config override, is that the numeric value for the boolean is wrapped in double quotes when the serializer is used. The deserializer does not care about this small detail and it's able to convert the number to Boolean just the same. I just thought it was a good idea to show how to create and use the serializer.

Comment: I will update with the deserialization part in a second....